# Ajax Contact form plugin

Tags: plugin-development

I am facing strange problem .I am building ajax contact form plugin.My problem
When I add jquery script in theme footer there is no problem at all everything works fine.
But if I add same script from plugin directory it does not work any more.My coding to add script .Please note that if ace.js is added in footer in script tag it works

Here is the source https://www.dropbox.com/s/8m64xzueohppuxd/ajax_contactform.zip

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts','webangon_ajax_contact'); 
function webangon_ajax_contact() {
wp_enqueue_script('ajcontact', plugins_url("/inc/ace.js", __FILE__),array(jquery));}
```

The form section

```
    <form method="post" id="mailinglist" action="">
<div id="message"></div>
<input type="text" name="mailinglistname" id="mailinglistname" placeholder="John Doe" /></br>
<input type="text" name="mailinglistemail" id="mailinglistemail" placeholder="johndoe@hotmail.com" /></br>
<textarea name="mailinglistcomment" id="mailinglistcomment" cols="58" rows="5" tabindex="4" placeholder="Do you develope websites for FREE?"></textarea></br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" class="read-more" id="mailinglistsubmit" value="Send" /><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/image/89.gif" alt="" class="ajaxsave" style="display: none;" />
</form>
```

The jquery part ace.js

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery("#mailinglist").submit(function()    {
    if(jQuery("#mailinglistname").val()=="") {
        jQuery("#mailinglist #message").text("Please enter your name.");
        return false;
    }       
    if(jQuery("#mailinglistemail").val()=="") {
        jQuery("#mailinglist #message").text("Please enter your email address.");
        return false;
    } else {
        var email = jQuery('#mailinglistemail').val();
        var name = jQuery('#mailinglistname').val();
        var comment = jQuery('#mailinglistcomment').val();
        if(email.indexOf("@") == -1 || email.indexOf(".") == -1) {
            jQuery("#mailinglist #message").text("Please enter a valid email address.");
            return false;
        } else {
            var data = {
                action: 'join_mailinglist',
                email: email,
                name:name,
                comment:comment,
            };
            jQuery("#mailinglistsubmit").hide();
            jQuery(".ajaxsave").show();
            jQuery.post("<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>", data,
            function(response){
                jQuery(".ajaxsave").hide();
                jQuery("#mailinglistsubmit").show();
                jQuery("#mailinglist #message").html(response);
            });     
            return false;
        }
    } 

});
```

});

Finally ajax admin part

```
add_action('wp_ajax_join_mailinglist', 'join_mailinglist_callback');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_join_mailinglist', 'join_mailinglist_callback');
function join_mailinglist_callback() {
$email = $_POST['email'];
$name = $_POST['name'];
$comment = $_POST['comment'];
$emailTo = "raisulangon@hotmail.com";
$body = "Name: $name Email: $email Comment: $comment";
if(wp_mail($emailTo, $name,$body)){
echo "<div class='success'>Enquiry has been sent successfully</div>";
}
else
{
echo "<div class='error'>Please Try Again</div>";
}
die();
}
```

Comment: Is this exactly how your code looks? If so, make sure you add quotes around jquery in wp_enqueue_script like

`wp_enqueue_script('ajcontact', plugins_url("/inc/ace.js", __FILE__),array("jquery"));`

Comment: Thank you for your edit but It is not working

Comment: Is there a website where I can see what is happening? Which part is not working? Is the javascript not added at all?

Comment: Go through your source code on the browser and see if the JavaScript file is there.

Comment: I have added dropbox link please see the edit

Comment: Found it admin-ajax url path is not correct.How can I do this with localise script?

Comment: Ashraf, please calm down and be nice. I have misread `.submit()` with `.click()`. Stil you are missing `event.preventDefault()` to keep the form from reloading the request, have PHP in your `ace.js` JavaScript file: `jQuery.post("<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>"`, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
wp_register_script('ajcontact', plugins_url("/inc/ace.js", __FILE__),array('jquery'));
wp_localize_script('ajcontact', 'MyAjax', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ));
wp_enqueue_script('ajcontact');
```

And then in your ace.js do

```
jQuery.post(MyAjax.ajaxurl, data, ....
```

Comment: Almost done but ajax functionality breaks.It refreshes the whole page

Comment: Are you able to inspect the page? If so, do you see any javascript errors?

Comment: No error found but the form input value are not sent to admin ajax.